# LabelEncoder changes values of original dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 1 data frame named: FilterTrain [image]

I want to encode the 'gender' values; for this I have taken another dataframe named EncodedTrain and storing the resulting dataframe in itself, I am getting my desired results in EncodedTrain[image]

But as you can see the values of gender are also being encoded in the original dataframe (FilterTrain).

Comment: By using `EncodedTrain=FilterTrain`, you are making them point to the same location in memory, so changing one object, you will change the other. use `EncodedTrain=FilterTrain.copy()` or something instead

Comment: Using python for the first time.Thanks sir.